# What's a safe way to define a function if it's not defined already

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I've got some code like this, which attempts to define `foobar` if it isn't already defined:

```
if (!foobar) {
  function foobar() {
    alert("hello from foobar");
  }
}
```

Calling `foobar` outside of that block works in Chrome, but not in Firefox (see http://jsbin.com/kifeticesa/1/edit?html,js,output - Firefox gives me a `ReferenceError`, I think because of declaration hoisting - this apparently [isn't a new problem](http://statichtml.com/2011/spidermonkey-function-hoisting.html)).

I think a better way of writing this is:

```
function foobar_impl() {
  alert("hello from foobar");
}

if ('foobar' == typeof window.noFunc) {
   var foobar = foobar_impl;
}
```

But I'd value any other ideas, or some documentation I can read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems fairly idiomatic:

```
var foobar = foobar || function() {
    /*...*/
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!window.foobar) {
    window.foobar = function() {
        alert("hello from foobar"); 
    }
}
foobar(); // alerts "hello from foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how MDN checks for functions before implementing polyfills:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function <...>
```

<sub>[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)</sub>

This is pretty much equivalent to:

```
if (!window.foobar) {
    window.foobar = function() {
        alert("hello from foobar");
    }
}
```

Which should fix the hoisting issue.

Just make sure you keep scope in mind.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good (and I'm really grateful for the MDN link). What do I need to keep in mind about scope?

Comment: `window` is the global scope. In case you're working with some kind of "OOP" format, functions might be declared in another "class"'s scope (In a different `function`'s scope)